# No hand tracking during holographic remoting on Hololens 2 with Unity 2020.3/OpenXR/MRTK 2.8

Tags: unity-game-engine, remote-debugging, hololens, mrtk, openxr

I've been developing a Hololens 2 app in Unity 2019.4 using built-in XR/Windows Mixed Reality and remoting was working fine, hand tracking was perfect. Recently migrated to Unity 2020.3 LTS using OpenXR. Everything is working fine in the editor/player and I'm able to connect to my HL2 for remoting (following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/preview-and-debug-your-app?tabs=openxr)) but then things get weird:

When I play remotely, the scene origin doesn't line up how it used to - often the scene loads behind and/or below me. During normal non-remoting play, the origin is exactly where I'd expect it. And I'm unable to get any kind of hand tracking in the headset.

I've tried importing DotNetWinRT and [other troubleshooting steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/tools/holographic-remoting?source=recommendations&view=mrtkunity-2022-05) but nothing works.

My Unity 2019 packages:

[image: 2019 packages]

My Unity 2020 packages:

[image: 2020 packages]

Unity 2020 OpenXR Project Settings:

[image: 2020 OpenXR Settings]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mre] (just enough info to reproduce the problem). See [ask] for further guidance on asking questions. Please also [edit] to add a transcription of your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: @starball sorry I'm not sure how best to provide a minimal reproducable example beyond the screenshots and explanation I've already provided. If there are any specifics or additional info you'd like to know, I'll do my best to provide. I tried in-lining the screenshots, but it keeps formatting them as links.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. Did you already read the the Help Center page on what questions are on-topic here? If so, can you explain to my why this is on topic? (since I'm not sure). If not, please read it and consider whether your question is on-topic here. If you're not sure where to ask this question, you can ask on meta.stackexchange.com and tag it with \[site-recommendation\].

Comment: To clarify, the plugin Mixed Reality WinRT Projections works with XR SDK, while Unity 2020.3 LTS uses Open XR, so you don't need to install this plugin. For the scene origin, the default is based on the position and orientation of your head, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/design/coordinate-systems for more information.

Comment: For hand tracking, are you saying that the hands are not detected and tracked properly by the device, and you can't use the hands to interact? Or do you mean the hand mesh is not visualized? Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/hand-tracking?view=mrtkunity-2022-05.

Comment: In the last screenshot, you have to also check the settings under the windows icon(for UWP platform) as far as I know XR Management.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to manually update the Input Data Providers in the MixedRealityToolkit. If I'd created this scene from scratch, I imagine these data providers would have been properly configured by Unity, but because I was migrating the scene from a previous Unity/Mixed Reality version, they never got updated.

[MRTK Input settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sWER.png)